# how to call admin Carrier add after hook in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I want execute some code when admin carrier add after, how to call the hook name?

I found the `hookActionObjectCarrierAddAfter` but I can not get the params or carrier last insert.

Comment: Did you try the below solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your module you should use:

```php
class MyModule extends Module
{
    public function install()
    {
        if (! parent::install() || ! $this->registerHook('actionObjectCarrierAddAfter'))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function hookActionObjectCarrierAddAfter($params)
    {
        $carrier = $params['object'];

        [...]
    }

}
```

This hook is called from the method `add` of class `ObjectModel`:

```php
public function add($auto_date = true, $null_values = false)
{
    if (isset($this->id) && !$this->force_id) {
        unset($this->id);
    }

    // @hook actionObject*AddBefore
    Hook::exec('actionObjectAddBefore', array('object' => $this));
    Hook::exec('actionObject'.get_class($this).'AddBefore', array('object' => $this));

    // [...]
    // [...]
    // [...]

    // @hook actionObject*AddAfter
    Hook::exec('actionObjectAddAfter', array('object' => $this));
    Hook::exec('actionObject'.get_class($this).'AddAfter', array('object' => $this));

    return $result;
}
```